# simultaneously smoothly reorder and make appear new word segments on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to put a title above a page that (hypothetically) says: DUKE YAHA
On hover, I want the text to smoothly transition (actually using CSS3 transition, not just instantly changing) to: ARCH**DUKE**MAN *AY*HA**TON**
So, what gets added is ARCH and MAN before and after DUKE; and in YAHA, the Y and A switch places, and TON is added after. So two things:

1. words are added;
2. letters are switched around

What I would want to achieve is that DUKE moves to the left to make space for ARCH and MAN around it; and that you see the letters Y and A in YAHA actually switch places.

I don't mean to ask for someone to write it all out for me because it's a lot of work, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be amazing!

For instance, to achieve this, should I look at jQuery rather than CSS3 (which I've been trying but no luck)? And should I use CSS3 animation besides CSS3 transition to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```js
$( ".top" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).find('.letters').addClass( "active" );
  });
```

```css
.letters{
        -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
        float: left;
        position:relative ;
    }
    .first , .third,.seven{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .top{
        left: 55%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        width: 400px;
    }
    .first, .third,.seven{
        -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
        -o-transition-delay: 1s;
        -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
        transition-delay: 1s;
    }
    .second{
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(35px,0px,0px);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(35px,0px,0px);
        -o-transform: translate3d(35px,0px,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(35px,0px,0px);
        transform: translate3d(35px,0px,0px);
        -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
        -o-transition-delay: 0s;
        -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
        transition-delay: 0s;

    }
 
    .fourth{
            transform: translate3d(11px,0px,0px);
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(11px,0px,0px);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(11px,0px,0px);
            -o-transform: translate3d(11px,0px,0px);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(11px,0px,0px);
            -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
            -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
            -o-transition-delay: 2s;
            -ms-transition-delay: 2s;
            transition-delay: 2s;

        }
    .fivth{
            transform: translate3d(-10px,0px,0px);
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0px,0px);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(-10px,0px,0px);
            -o-transform: translate3d(-10px,0px,0px);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(-10px,0px,0px);
            -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
            -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
            -o-transition-delay: 2s;
            -ms-transition-delay: 2s;
            transition-delay: 2s;
        }

    .active{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
        transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="top">
        <span class="letters first">ARCH  </span>
        <span class="letters second"> DUKE </span>
        <span class="letters third"> MAN </span>
        <span class="letters">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="letters fourth">A</span>
        <span class="letters fivth">Y</span>
        <span class="letters six">HA</span>
        <span class="letters seven">TON</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Waow that did it *exactly* - thank you so much for your time on this! Once I have enough reputation to upvote, I'll come back here and upvote it hard! :)